# How do I best construct a shapeless record with a default value?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Say I have a shapeless record:

```
trait T
case object Ti extends T
case object Ta extends T
case object To extends T

type R = Record.`Ta -> Option[String], Ti -> Option[Int]`.T
val r: R = (Ta ->> Option("plif")) :: (Ti ->> Option(4)) :: HNil
```

I'd like to write a function `get` such that:

```
get(Ta) == Some("plif")
get(Ti) == Some(4)
get(To) == None
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What does your class `X` look like? BTW, it is easier to try out your code when you provide all required import statements.

Comment: I've simplified the question so it focuses on the important part. Hopefully that should make it easier to answer.

Comment: That doesn't solve your problem, but as for your original question: in `X`, you provide only type `K` with `k`, so `V` and `M` aren't known and should be calculated with implicits. But the `merger` tries to use `V` immediately, so it doesn't work. I've managed to make it compile like this: `class X[K <: T, OV, V, M <: HList](val k: K)(implicit s1: Selector.Aux[A.R, K, OV], ev: OV <:< Option[V], merger: Merger.Aux[FieldType[K, Option[V]] :: HNil, A.R, M], s: Selector.Aux[M, K, Option[V]]) extends A[K, V]`. `s1` calculates `V` from `R`, `ev` unwraps `Option`, and then go your `merger` and `s`.

Comment: What should be the type of `get(To)`? `Option[Nothing]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to provide your own `Selector` instance for a default case:

```
class DefaultSelector[R <: HList, K] extends Selector[R, K] {
  type Out = Option[Nothing]
  def apply(l: R): Out = None
}

def get[K, V](k: K)(
  implicit sel: Selector[R, K] = new DefaultSelector[R, K]
): sel.Out = sel(r)
```

But with that code Scala's compiler may have difficulties providing `TypeTag`s for the result of the default case.

---

So to fix that you can also write a new typeclass `DefaultSelector`, which will default to `None: Option[Nothing]`, if no `Selector` is found:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.record._

trait DefaultSelector[R <: HList, K] {
  type Out
  def apply(r: R): Out
}

sealed trait LowPriorityDefaultSelector {
  type Aux[R <: HList, K, V] = DefaultSelector[R, K] { type Out = V }

  case class Impl[R <: HList, K, V](get: R => V) extends DefaultSelector[R, K] {
    type Out = V
    def apply(r: R): Out = get(r)
  }

  implicit def default[R <: HList, K, V](
    implicit ev: Option[Nothing] =:= V  // tricking Scala's implicit resolution
  ): Aux[R, K, V] =
    Impl[R, K, V](Function.const(None))
}

object DefaultSelector extends LowPriorityDefaultSelector {
  implicit def existing[R <: HList, K, V](
    implicit sel: Selector.Aux[R, K, V]
  ): Aux[R, K, V] =
    Impl[R, K, V](sel.apply)
}
```

Then the `get` function becomes:

```
def get[K, V](k: K)(implicit sel: DefaultSelector[R, K]): sel.Out = sel(r)
```

---

And the result (for both solutions) is:

```
scala> get(Ti)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(4)

scala> get(Ta)
res1: Option[String] = Some(plif)

scala> get(To)
res2: Option[Nothing] = None
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution, but I wonder if there is any way to avoid the =:=. The operator is blocking for concurrent applications so it decreases performance quite a lot.

Comment: It turns out that I tend to know the return key type even when the value isn't present in the record, so your first solution is a really nice and simple way of doing things. It had never occurred to me that it would be possible to provide a default value to an implicit value.

Comment: @arnfred Can you explain, please, why is `=:=` blocking? Well, ideally this `default` should be `implicit def default[R <: HList, K]: Aux[R, K, Option[Nothing]] = Impl[R, K, Option[Nothing]](Function.const(None))`, but this won't compile because of quirks in Scala's overloaded implicits resolution. So I needed `default` to be "less specific" according to the definition in §6.26.3 of the spec, and couldn't come up with a better way to do it.